# Highcharts flag text position issue with different shapes

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have added some flags of different shapes in my highcharts with some text inside it. But the text position does not look so professional as it must be. I have attached the screenshot of those flags also. (by using style:{marginLeft:5px} it's not working).

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately I was not able to replicate your issue: http://jsfiddle.net/ggg6024d/ / http://jsfiddle.net/3ctsej8r/. Could you update my demo with your code and let me know about your browser details?

Comment: Hi @SebastianBochan Thanks for your reply,
I am using Google Chrome
 see this fiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/sorb999/u180n7nt/3/
) In above image you will see letter 'F' inside triangle does not appear with proper margin. It should take a little margin to right. And should be at the center of that flag.

Comment: I created a possibily bug case here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/5980. So please add a comment if somehitng is unclear.